# I'm getting "None" in the config path, when trying to download the model, from CoquiTTS

Tags: python, nlp, text-to-speech, gtts

I'm trying this piece of code:

```
from TTS.api import TTS
from TTS.utils.manage import ModelManager   
from TTS.utils.synthesizer import Synthesizer

path = "C:/Users/sanca/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages/TTS/.models.json"

model_manager = ModelManager(path)

model_path, config_path, model_item = model_manager.download_model("tts_models/multilingual/multi-dataset/xtts_v2")

print(config_path)

syn = Synthesizer(
    tts_checkpoint=model_path,
    tts_config_path=config_path
)

text = "I am a text readed by a computer "

outputs = syn.tts(text)
syn.save_wav(outputs, "audio.wav")
```

However, when I try to print the config_path I get None, and that is causing everything to not work :(

I've tried to --upgrade TTS, and to change the path, this is the error I get:

```
 > tts_models/multilingual/multi-dataset/xtts_v2 is already downloaded.
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanca\Documents\Bookypy\main2.py", line 13, in <module>
    syn = Synthesizer(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sanca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\TTS\utils\synthesizer.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._load_tts(tts_checkpoint, tts_config_path, use_cuda)
  File "C:\Users\sanca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\TTS\utils\synthesizer.py", line 183, in _load_tts
    self.tts_config = load_config(tts_config_path)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sanca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\TTS\config\__init__.py", line 85, in load_config
    ext = os.path.splitext(config_path)[1]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen ntpath>", line 232, in splitext
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Thx in advance.